# Taylor vs Laurent series - cosines and sines

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

In general, why do we say that the Taylor series of sines and cosines are also Laurent series despite of the power of $z$?

Comment: Any Taylor series is also a Laurent series, but not conversely.

Comment: I know, but the power of $z$ should be $z^n$, not $z^{2n+1}$ or $z^{2n}$? I think it is a silly question, but I would to know why.

Comment: That just means all the odd powers of $z$ (for cosine) or all the even powers of $z$ (for sine) have a coefficient of $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $2n+1$ in the exponent in the series expansion for $\sin$ is a shorthand, since
$$ \sin z = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^{(j)}(0) z^j}{j!}
$$
the coefficients $\sin^{(j)}(0)/j!$ evaluates to $0$ when $j$ is even, hence they can be skipped.

Comment: Which pills do you take to stay awake? ;)

Comment: @Pi neuf Time zone pills.